# How to write a function that raises a number to 10th power using Racket?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

This is what I have:

```
(define (10th-power 10 y)
 (if (= y 0)
 1
 (* 10 ((10th-power 10 (- y 1)))))
```

for example if I input 2 it should give out 1024.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in this short procedure. Here are the errors reported by racket:

- `read: expected a ')' to close '('` since you are missing ending parentheis
- `define: not an identifier... in 10` as 10  cannot be a variable name it cannot be in the argument list.
- `application: not a procedure`. Double parentheses in the recursion part makes the result from `10th-power` tried as a procedure as the result instead of just using the value as is.

If you fix those your procedure will work, but it will do the `10^y` instead of `y^10`. Perhaps you need a helper where you keep how many times you have multiplied `y` that counts down instead of `y` which is the one that should be in 10's place.

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
#lang racket

(define (10th-power y)
  (if (= y 0)
      1
      (* 10 (10th-power (- y 1)))))

(10th-power 3)
```

Things to note: You can't insert an extra parenthesis around an expression. Example: `(100)` means call 100 with no arguments - and since 100 is not a function, you get the error "application: not a procedure:.

Second thing to note: You do not need the 10 as an argument.

Comment: I see. (10th-power 3) outputs 1000. I think it is doing 10*10*10. It should be 3^10 and output 59049.

Comment: The shortest way of computing `3*...*3` is `(for/product ([n 10]) 3)` but if you are practising recursion, I'd follow the advice of Sylwester (i.e. introduce a helper function).

Answer (score 1):

you can write a recursion like this:

```
#lang racket
(define (10th-power y)
  (if (= y 0 )
      1
      (* 10 (10th-power (- y 1)))))
```

by the way, if you want to improve you space efficiency from o(n) to o(1),you can write iteration:

```
#lang racket
(define (10th-power y)
  (define (iter back times)
    (if (= times 0)
        back
        (iter (* 10 back) (- times 1))))
  (iter 1 y))

(10th-power 3)
```